Where can I find a setup example for Sustainsys.Saml2.mvc in Program.cs
I would like the using statment required and all options required for a .Net 6 and greater c# MVC web application in the Program.cs.  Thank you!
Tried these using statements at the top of Program.cs - using Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata; using Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.
The following is not recognized in Program.cs to begin trying the options: builder.Services.AddSaml2
